# Query goes in Copying to tmp table stauts in MySQL and never returns

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I am getting some strange behaviors for my MySQL query status. Here is my query code:

```
SELECT a.id as art_id, b.album_artist_id,
s.song_title,s.song_seo,a.artist_seo,a.artist_name,
b.album_title, b.album_picture, s.id,s.picture 
FROM tbl_artist_album b, tbl_artists a, tbl_songs_artist_album saa, tbl_songs s
WHERE 1=1
  AND s.id = saa.song_id AND a.id = saa.artist_id 
  AND b.id = saa.album_id AND saa.artist_id != 67 
  AND ( MATCH (s.song_title) AGAINST ('taylor swift*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
  AND (CONCAT(s.song_title) LIKE '%taylor swift%') 
  AND s.song_status = 1 
group by s.id 
ORDER BY s.song_title = 'taylor swift' desc 
LIMIT 50
```

When I execute above query in Phpmyadmin panel it works fine and returns 0 results with in few seconds.
But When the query is executed from browser by search form on a page , the query goes directly in the "Copy to tmp table" status and never returns anything.

```
| 79 | | | | |  632 | Copying to tmp table | select a.id as art_id,b.album_artist_id,s.song_title,s.song_seo,a.artist_seo,a.artist_name,b.album_title, b.album_picture, s.id,s.picture from tbl_artist_album b, tbl_artists a, tbl_songs_artist_album saa, tbl_songs s where 1=1 AND s.id = saa.song_id AND a.id = saa.artist_id AND b.id = saa.album_id AND saa.artist_id != 67 AND s.song_title like 'taylor swift%'  AND s.song_status = 1 group by s.id order by s.song_title = 'taylor swift' desc limit 50 |
```

I have also attached the screenshot of query execution for reference[image: here] in Phpmyadmin and it work in few seconds but I am confused why it is showing "copy to tmp table" when executed from browser.

Comment: What's the `1 = 1` for? And `ORDER BY s.song_title = 'taylor swift'`? Surely, given your `MATCH` clause above, surely they'll all have `taylor swift`? Just have `ORDER BY s.song_title DESC`. Try and put the query into ANSI `JOIN` syntax - mightn't make much of a difference, but it is more legible (used to hate it myself, now can't do it any other way!). And what does `AND (CONCAT(s.song_title) LIKE '%taylor swift%')` do? Whey not just have (remove `MATCH` and `CONCAT`) `AND s.song_title LIKE '%taylor_swift%'`? Anyway, shouldn't that be `a.artist_name`?

Comment: But this is not just happening with this query, all the queries are going in "copy to tmp table" status and hanging and the same queries are working fine in phpmyadmin panel. I am helpless now.

Comment: I was just trying to "simplify" the query! However, if you look at your query as written out by you and the one copied and pasted (line beginning `79`), you will see that they are different - this could be **part** of the problem? Getting the query "ship-shape" might be a start to resolving your issue?

Comment: @Vérace - `ORDER BY s.song_title = 'taylor swift' DESC` puts the `exact match` first.

Comment: @Vérace - Having both `MATCH` and `LIKE` is a tricky way to get the speed of `FULLTEXT`, but the "exact match" of `Taylor` _immediately_ followed by `Swift`.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't explain why one call was 'fast' and the other was 'slow'.)

The "copying to tmp table" provides virtually no useful info.  It *may* be saying that it is busy shoveling around more than 50 (re: `LIMIT`) rows collected from the 4 tables.  My fix, below, mitigates that.

Try the following rewrite as an attempt to speed things up.

First -- Find the ids for "Taylor Swift" songs.  (But would that be in the `title`??)
Second -- Get the rest of the data and do the `JOINs`.

The rationale -- Get the complex, slow, parts of the query over with before rummaging around in multiple tables.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM tbl_songs
        WHERE ( MATCH (song_title) AGAINST ('taylor swift*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
          AND (CONCAT(song_title) LIKE '%taylor swift%') 
          AND song_status = 1
        ORDER BY s.song_title = 'taylor swift' desc
        LIMIT 50 ) AS s1
    JOIN tbl_songs AS s2  ON s1.id = s2.id
    JOIN ... the-other-tables
        ON ...
    WHERE  ...  the-filtering
    ORDER BY s.song_title = 'taylor swift' desc 
    LIMIT 50
```

Yes, the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are needed twice.

The hope is that `MATCH` is performed first, leading to much fewer rows to apply the `LIKE` to.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

The `1=1` is a common technique for building the `WHERE` clause.  It is harmless, but it would be better to gather an array of `AND` clauses and put them together at the end, not building a string as you go.

Check `innodb_buffer_pool_size` -- is it about 70% of *available* RAM?